# jQuery Height Adjustment

Tags: jquery, css, height

Is there any way to say: IF John's height is larger THAN Mike's height THEN make Mike's height equal to John's height?
CSS (although I don't believe this can be done with CSS) or jQuery.

See the image --> http://i50.tinypic.com/2ecdstw.jpg to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with jQuery using the [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) style property.

```
if($(".john").height() > $(".mike").height())
{
    $(".john").height($(".mike").height());
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Demo of above code](http://codepen.io/pen/319/1)

Comment: Seems to work just fine.... http://codepen.io/pen/319/1 You can remove the javascript and see what it looks like with out the jquery code as well.

Comment: I've replaced the $ with jQuery and works fine! Many thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 1):

```
var john = $("#john").css('height'), //use css
    mike = $("#mike").height(); //or just the height() method

if (john>mike) mike=john;
```

Comment: adeneo thanks for your answer. The problem is that John's height won't be always the same. It's height depends on how long the contained article will be.

Comment: I realize that, but that's what jQuery's css() and height() functions are for!

Comment: also how to select them in jQuery? John and Mike are containers

Comment: Maybe you should look at jQuery's documentation, it's way better documented there then we can explain in a simple post here?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.fn.equalHeight = function(){
    var h = 0;
    this.each(function(){
        h = Math.max(h, $(this).height());
    }).height(h);
 };
```

Is this small plugin it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/inewen/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$(".elements").height(Math.max.apply(null, $(".elements").map(function () {
    return $(this).height();
}).get()));
```

---

### *Here is the CSS only solution:*

```
  .el_wrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    overflow:hidden;
  }      
  .el{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    background:#eee;
    margin:3px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:-3000px;
    padding-bottom:3015px;
  }
```

### *[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/inewen/4/edit)*

Comment: Very useful example but heights will not always be the same.

Comment: @ArgGeo I really don't understand your comment... I know that! Have you played with the heights? It will always find the highest one and set all the other elements to that height! You don't want that? (P.S. remove/comment-out the jQuery in the demo and you'll see that he heights are NOT the same)

Comment: @ArgGeo I added also the CSS solution. Take a look.

Comment: The problem is that this code will make equal every height. I want only 2 columns with the same height! Ryan's solutions is the most appropriate in my situation. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: But Arg Geo...than use it only on two columns... :( http://jsbin.com/inewen/5/edit I really don't undersatand your Q. You need it only one-way height... looks like.